# T-SQL Error while DECLARING variables

Tags: visual-studio, t-sql

```
Declare @ID nvarchar(14) = '12345678912345'  
DECLARE @Key int = (SELECT  key
                           FROM    table
                           WHERE   id = @ID) 

Declare @indicator varchar(1) = 'A' 

Declare @rdate Datetime = (SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(Left(CAST(GetDate() AS Datetime2),23))))


SELECT @ID 
GO
SELECT @Key 
GO
SELECT @indicator 
GO
SELECT @date 
GO
```

I get error when I execute the above code. I see @ID print and it goes away and I get the following messages.

"Must declare the scalar variable "@Key"

"Must declare the scalar variable "@indicator"

"Must declare the scalar variable "@date"

Datatypes in the table: ID = nvarchar(14), key = int, indicator = varchar(1), and date = timestamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Go` will end the scope and destroy the variables.

Use a `;` instead

```
SELECT @ID;SELECT @Key;SELECT @indicator;SELECT @rdate;
```

Comment: Wow...that solved it. Now if I have a bunch of DML statements and each ends with GO, is it OK if I remove GO after each DML statements?